# Are there any data-sets having multiple multivariate time-series with causal relations between its attributes along with their description?

Tags: data-request, uses-of-open-data, time-series

I need to perform some data-analysis task. For that I need data-sets containing multiple multivariate(multidimensional) time-series. Along with that I also need the description of each dimension, so the domain knowledge can be used for analyzing the data.

Comment: Hi @Sushodhan, I would suggest using several time series with a common temporal frequency.  Have you tried searching for time series dataset sources using a search engine?  Something like [FRED](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/) or the [World Bank](https://datacatalog.worldbank.org/data-type/time-series) might be good places to start.

Comment: @sboysel thanks for the reply. I searched the World Bank database, and I have also used some of the time-series from it which met my requirements for my experiments. However I need more such time-series and it would be better if they are from different domain. Also thank you for suggesting [FRED] (https://fred.stlouisfed.org/). I will search for some in it.